# Informar dato de una lista dentro de un contenedor, e incrementar 1

Tags: python, diccionarios, contenedores

Tengo el siguiente enunciado. Se que es muy básico, pero no logro darme cuenta como acceder a los datos dentro del contenedor para poder sumarlo.

Escribí un programa que almacene la información relacionada con pacientes: edad, sexo DNI, y si es diabético.
Utilizá un diccionario para registrar los datos provistos (deberás utilizar un contenedor para los valores).

Solicitar al usuario un DNI e incrementar en 1 la edad del paciente correspondiente.

Lo que hice hasta el momento:

```
datos = {"Edad:":[60, 65, 45, 34, 58, 23],
     "DNI:":[11412625, 6409217, 19172162, 28141815, 14972142, 36843316],
     "Sexo:":["M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F"],
     "Es diabetico?":["Si", "No", "No", "Si", "Si", "No"]} 

dni = input("ingrese dni: ")
for dni in datos:
    for i in datos["DNI:"]:
       datos.update({"Edad:"[i]:[i]+1})
print(datos)
```

Comment: Buen día, tengo algunas preguntas 1. ¿El diccionario datos te lo dieron o tu lo creaste? Porque según lo que yo entiendo del diccionario sería hacer otra cosa. 2. ¿Te pidieron utilizar `update`? Porque se podría hacer de otra forma. 3. ¿Lo único que hay que hacer es, recibir un DNI por el `input` buscarlo dentro de los datos existentes e incrementar la edad?

Comment: 1. Si, el diccionario me lo dieron. 2. No, es lo que a mi se me ocurrio. 3. Exacto

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El primer paso en la solución es encontrar una representación conveniente para los datos.

En este problema se manejan los datos de personas. Los datos de **una** persona se pueden representar con un diccionario donde las llaves son `edad`, `sexo`, `diabetico`.

Como tengo varias personas, las pondré en un diccionario indexado por DIN.

```
datos = {"11412625" : {"Edad": 60, "Sexo": "M", "diabetico": False},
         "11412700" : {"Edad": 62, "Sexo": "F", "diabetico": False},
         "11412987" : {"Edad": 65, "Sexo": "M", "diabetico": True}
         }
```

Recuperar los datos de una persona ahora no requiere búsqueda. Simplemente se usa el DIN para encontrarla:

```
datos = {"11412625" : {"Edad": 60, "Sexo": "M", "diabetico": False},
         "11412700" : {"Edad": 62, "Sexo": "F", "diabetico": False},
         "11412987" : {"Edad": 65, "Sexo": "M", "diabetico": True}
         }


dni = input("ingrese dni: ")
datos[dni]["Edad"] += 1
print(datos)
```

produce:

```
ingrese dni: 11412625
{'11412625': {'Edad': 61, 'Sexo': 'M', 'diabetico': False}, '11412700': {'Edad': 62, 'Sexo': 'F', 'diabetico': False}, '11412987': {'Edad': 65, 'Sexo': 'M', 'diabetico': True}}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Ya que todos los elementos dentro de `datos` son listas, podrías utilizar el método [index()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_index.asp) de las listas para obtener el índice del valor del "DNI" ingresado en el `input` y luego incrementar la edad.

**Nota:** Como "DNI" tiene valores numéricos de tipo `int` debes convertir el valor del `input` a entero:

```
dni = int(input("ingrese dni: "))
```

Ejemplo completo

```
datos = {"Edad:":[60, 65, 45, 34, 58, 23],
     "DNI:":[11412625, 6409217, 19172162, 28141815, 14972142, 36843316],
     "Sexo:":["M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F"],
     "Es diabetico?":["Si", "No", "No", "Si", "Si", "No"]} 

dni = int(input("ingrese dni: "))

datos['Edad:'][datos['DNI:'].index(dni)] += 1

print(datos)
```

Muestra:

```
[In:] ingrese dni:  11412625
[Out:] {'Edad:': [61, 65, 45, 34, 58, 23], 'DNI:': [11412625, 6409217, 19172162, 28141815, 14972142, 36843316], 'Sexo:': ['M', 'F', 'M', 'F', 'M', 'F'], 'Es diabetico?': ['Si', 'No', 'No', 'Si', 'Si', 'No']}
```

Se puede ver que al ingresar el primer "DNI" el valor de la edad con el mismo índice incrementa en 1

Para acceder a cualquier valor del diccionario se utiliza el nombre del diccionario y el nombre de la llave, por ejemplo:

```
print(datos['Edad:'])
```

Esto devolvería todas las edades

```
[60, 65, 45, 34, 58, 23]
```

Si quieres acceder a una edad en específico puedes hacerlo con el número del índice, por ejemplo la primera edad sería

```
print(datos['Edad:'][0])
```

Que sería el valor `60` del diccionario original (Claro que si lo editas devolvería otro valor)

Por lo tanto, para actualizar el valor de la edad primero buscamos el índice del "DNI" que contenga el valor ingresado en el `input` que en el caso del ejemplo es `0` por estar en la primera posición. Luego utilizamos ese valor para acceder al mismo índice pero de la llave "Edad:" y lo actualizamos.